# How to Get List Sorted by Time(ASC/DESC) Using The Command "find . -type f -ls" in Linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, find, ls

How to Get List Sorted by Time(ASC/DESC) Using The Command "find . -type f -ls" in Linux?

1. I want to use find command.
2. I want to get result like using "ls".

> find . -type f -ls

[As-Is]

5113588    0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root  0  Jul 31 15:26 ./bbb.txt

5113222    0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root  0  Jul 17 13:18 ./aaa.txt

[To-Be]

5113222    0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root  0  Jul 17 13:18 ./aaa.txt

5113588    0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root  0  Jul 31 15:26 ./bbb.txt

If it's impossible, how can I get list including these by using any other commands?
1. File size
2. Time
3. File path and name
4. Include Child Directories

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

find / -type f -printf "\n%AD %AT %p" | head -n 11 | du -sh

Answer (score 0):

this will also work, here 
ls -lhStr

-l     use a long listing format
-h     with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-S     sort by file size

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry. I want to get the list including children directories.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I got it!

```
find . -type f -exec ls {} -al \;
```